# Bad state: Unexpected diagnostics: after flutter upgrade to 1.20.1

Tags: flutter, dart, chopper

What is the issue?

```
xxx@xxx-Inspiron-14-3467:~/xxx$ flutter pub run build_runner build[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 406ms

[WARNING] Deleted previous snapshot due to missing asset graph.
[INFO] Creating build script snapshot......
[INFO] Creating build script snapshot... completed, took 14.6s

[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Building new asset graph...
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 773ms

[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs....
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 1ms

[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] Generating SDK summary...
[SEVERE] chopper_generator:chopper_generator on test/widget_test.dart:

Bad state: Unexpected diagnostics:
/home/xxx/Desktop/flutter_linux_1.20.1-stable/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/core/uri.dart:3259:39 - Expected an identifier.
[SEVERE] chopper_generator:chopper_generator on test/widget_test.dart:

Bad state: Unexpected diagnostics:
/home/xxx/Desktop/flutter_linux_1.20.1-stable/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/core/uri.dart:3259:39 - Expected an identifier.
[INFO] 1.6s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 2.7s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 3.8s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 4.9s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 6.0s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 7.1s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 8.2s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 9.3s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 10.4s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 11.5s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 12.6s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 13.7s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 14.8s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[WARNING] No actions completed for 15.1s, waiting on:
  - chopper_generator:chopper_generator on lib/repository/model/radio_model.dart
  - chopper_generator:chopper_generator on lib/repository/model/xxx.dart
  - chopper_generator:chopper_generator on lib/repository/model/time.dart
  - chopper_generator:chopper_generator on lib/repository/model/assign_to.dart
  - chopper_generator:chopper_generator on lib/repository/model/defect_cases_count.dart
  .. and 11 more
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63556

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After spending more that 3 hours, finally I managed to solved.

For those who have upgraded to flutter version 1.20.1 or above, make sure you add this line in `pubspec.yaml`.

```
dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: '0.39.14'
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue:

Please try this in your pubspec file

```
dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: '0.39.17'    
  build_resolvers: '1.3.10'
```

Comment: Just `analyzer: ^0.39.17` straight in dev_dependecies worked for me

Answer (score 0):

try it:

1- `flutter clean`

2- go on dev channel: `flutter channel dev`

3- upgrade: `flutter upgrade --force`

4- `flutter pub get`

5- try to build

6- back on stable or master channel: `flutter channel stable` (`flutter channel master`)

7- upgrade: `flutter upgrade --force`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and if the accepted answer didn't solve your problem you can try the procedure described on [this issue](https://github.com/simolus3/moor/issues/553#issuecomment-674534334):

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`
- `flutter packages upgrade`