# Flutter crash after open apps

Tags: android, flutter, crash, codemagic

I usually build my mobile apps using build service from codemagic.com. During this week **i didnt change anything of my code** except build number.

Today I got my mobile phone crash after **new AppBundle Compile** with below error stack from `firebase console`.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
> No static method createAsync(Landroid/os/Looper;)Landroid/os/Handler; in class Landroidx/core/os/HandlerCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.os.HandlerCompat' appears in /data/app/exampleapps.exampleappsapps-BpzH5e6LIznAEB3YpE_SGw==/base.apk)

This crash occurs this week (last week was okay), this means **There's something update on the 3rd party plugin library or from flutter**, but I don't know which plugin causes this crash because I didn't change anything of my code.

Below are my `pubspec.yaml` specifications:

```
  rxdart_codemod: ^0.1.5
  angles: ^1.0.1
  app_settings: ^1.0.5
  archive: ^2.0.8
  flutter_cache_manager: ^1.4.0
  cached_network_image: ^2.2.0+1
  carousel_slider: ^1.3.0
  cron: ^0.2.1
  crypto: ^2.0.6
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  date_format: ^1.0.5
  device_id: ^0.1.3
  dio: ^3.0.9
  easy_alert: ^0.0.2
  localstorage: ^2.0.0
  audioplayers: ^0.13.1
  path_provider: ^1.1.0
  esys_flutter_share: ^1.0.2
  flutter_compass: ^0.3.2
  flutter_html: ^0.9.6
  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.8.2
  flutter_offline: ^0.2.4+1
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  flutter_xlider: ^2.4.5
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.2.0
  geolocator: ^5.0.1
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.2.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+1
  http: ^0.12.1
  libcalendar: ^0.2.0
  observable: ^0.22.2
  location : ^2.3.0
  numberpicker: ^1.0.0
  pigment: ^1.0.3
  
#   rxdart: ^0.24.1
  rxdart: ">=0.18.1 <0.24.1"
  
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+1
  shimmer: ^1.0.0
  unicode: ^0.1.0
  url_launcher: ^5.0.2
  validate: ^1.6.0
  vibrate: ^0.0.4

  # quran purpose
  after_layout: ^1.0.7+2
  draggable_scrollbar: ^0.0.4
  flutter_web_browser: ^0.11.0
  flutter_youtube: ^1.1.6
  google_api_availability: ^2.0.1
  indexed_list_view: ^0.0.5

  permission_handler: ^3.1.0
  queries: ^0.1.4
  rect_getter: ^0.0.1
  scroll_to_index: any
  sqflite: ^1.1.5
  tuple: ^1.0.2
  xml2json: ^3.0.3

  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6
  firebase_analytics: ^3.0.2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+3
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+6
  firebase_admob: ^0.9.0+1
  firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.0.1+3

  #button_style
  superellipse_shape: ^0.1.5

  #device info
  device_info: ^0.4.0+2

  #in-app-purchase
  in_app_purchase: ^0.2.0+6

  #realtime-error-reporting
  sentry: any

  #system_info
  system_info: ^0.1.1

  #highlight for tutorial
  highlighter_coachmark: ^0.0.3

  #detect sound
  volume: ^0.1.0
  
  #admob
  admob_flutter: ^0.3.2

  #other
  bubble_tab_indicator: "^0.1.4"
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^3.0.3289
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1
  flutter_slidable: ^0.4.9
  kiwi: ^0.1.0
  flutter_markdown: ^0.2.0

  #download & save file to storage
  flutter_downloader: ^1.2.1
  native_ads: ^0.2.0
  
  onesignal_flutter: ^2.0.0

  ##TEMPORARY DISABLED
  #flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
```

USB debug log:

> 08-17 11:18:42.282 12595 12600 I zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
> 08-17 11:18:42.283 12595 12595 I CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>
> --------- beginning of crash
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime: Process: exampleapps.exampleappsapps, PID: 12595
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:
> **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method createAsync(Landroid/os/Looper;)Landroid/os/Handler; in class Landroidx/core/os/HandlerCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.os.HandlerCompat' appears in /data/app/exampleapps.exampleappsapps-XKGzJQs6twT4qKb4AGKGTQ==/base.apk)**
>
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:   at androidx.work.impl.DefaultRunnableScheduler.**(DefaultRunnableScheduler.java:40)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at androidx.work.Configuration.(Configuration.java:106)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at androidx.work.Configuration$Builder.build(Configuration.java:434)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer.onCreate(WorkManagerInitializer.java:40)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6316)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5882)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5803)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6572)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
> 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
> 08-17 11:18:43.407   703   779 E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: perf_lock_rel: updated /sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/clk_scaling/enable with 0
> 08-17 11:18:43.407   703   779 E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER:  return value 2
> 08-17 11:18:44.199  2831  4931 I ActivityManager: Killing 10866:com.sonymobile.smartcharger/1000 (adj 906): empty #17
> 08-17 11:18:44.210  2831  4931 I ActivityManager: Killing 11915:com.discord/u0a315 (adj 906): empty #18
> 08-17 11:18:44.698   677   677 D audio_hw_primary: out_standby: enter: stream (0xf13d4000) usecase(1: low-latency-playback)
> 08-17 11:18:44.802   677   677 D audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
> 08-17 11:18:44.807   677   677 D hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
> 08-17 11:18:44.808   677   677 D audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(84: speaker)
> 08-17 11:18:44.829   677   677 D hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = vi-feedback
>
> 08-17 11:18:44.830   677   677 D audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(242: vi-feedback)
> 08-17 11:18:44.830   677   677 D msm8974_platform: platform_split_snd_device: snd_device(242) num devices(0) new_snd_devices(-238434933)
> 08-17 11:18:44.830   677   677 D audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: spkr-vi-record
> 08-17 11:18:44.867   677   677 D audio_hw_extn: audio_extn_get_anc_enabled: anc_enabled:0
> 08-17 11:18:44.867   677   677 D audio_hw_extn: audio_extn_get_anc_enabled: anc_enabled:0
> 08-17 11:18:44.867   677   677 D audio_hw_primary: out_standby: exit
> 08-17 11:18:46.288 12595 12595 E CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
> 08-17 11:18:46.288 12595 12595 E CrashlyticsCore: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
> 08-17 11:18:46.288 12595 12595 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
> 08-17 11:18:46.288 12595 12595 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:41)
> 08-17 11:18:46.288 12595 12595 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:321)
> 08-17 11:18:46.288 12595 12595 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:301)
> 08-17 11:18:46.288 12595 12595 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:42)
> 08-17 11:18:46.288 12595 12595 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
> 08-17 11:18:46.288 12595 12595 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
> 08-17 11:18:46.288 12595 12595 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1953)
> 08-17 11:18:46.301  2831  3677 D ActivityManager: New dropbox entry: exampleapps.exampleappsapps, data_app_crash, 3558ffd2-7966-4d8d-8ba6-2ceca752fb06
> 08-17 11:18:46.310  2831  3677 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity exampleapps.exampleappsapps/.MainActivity
> 08-17 11:18:46.313  2831  3677 D ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger
>
> 08-17 11:18:46.323  2831  3677 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.vending/.AssetBrowserActivity
> 08-17 11:18:46.335  2831  3677 I ActivityManager: Killing 12013:com.sonymobile.coverapp2/1000 (adj 906): empty #17
> 08-17 11:18:46.338 12111 12111 I Finsky  : [2] rjc.onTrimMemory(1): Memory trim requested to level 20
> 08-17 11:18:46.339 12111 12111 I Finsky  : [2] rjc.onTrimMemory(2): Flushing in-memory image cache
> 08-17 11:18:46.352  2831  2891 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
> 08-17 11:18:46.352  2831  2891 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
> 08-17 11:18:46.353  2831  2891 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.sonyericsson.crashmonitor/.receiver.CrashMonitorServiceBroadcastReceiver
> 08-17 11:18:46.356  2496  2496 I JavaDumper:main: dest_path: /data/system/log/jd_dropboxfiles/data_app_crash@1597637926341.txt
> 08-17 11:18:46.356  2496  2496 I JavaDumper:main: tot_read: 1699, tot_write: 1699
> 08-17 11:18:46.356  2496  2496 I JavaDumper:main: Successfully copied dropbox file to /data/system/log/jd_dropboxfiles/data_app_crash@1597637926341.txt
> 08-17 11:18:46.357  2496  2496 D clmlib  : Got activities:0x00000008
> 08-17 11:18:46.359 12111 12111 W ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend: Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
> 08-17 11:18:46.362 12111 12248 W ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend: Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
> 08-17 11:18:46.363  2496  2496 I JavaDumper:JavaDumperThread: addEvent: data_app_crash@1597637926341.txt processName: exampleapps.exampleappsapps
> 08-17 11:18:46.363  2496  2540 I JavaDumper:JavaDumperThread: Event: data_app_crash@1597637926341.txt TimeStamp: 1597637926
> 08-17 11:18:46.419  2496  2540 W JavaDumper:JavaDumper: Could not init dump dir: Unknown error -95
> 08-17 11:18:46.420  2496  2540 E JavaDumper:FW:  utils.c(257): mkdir (/data/crashdata) failed. File exists
> 08-17 11:18:46.423  2831  2893 I ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package exampleapps.exampleappsapps u0

any idea?

Comment: what is your flutter version?

Comment: @JohnJoe the last stable channel by codemagic.com but lastime, i change to 1.20.0

Comment: Do you have a pubspec.yaml copy before the update. Maybe that will help you in resolving the problem through comparing the versions of packages

Comment: maybe try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373620/build-runner-is-failing-after-flutter-upgrade-to-1-20-1

Comment: Migrate to AndroidX

Comment: @AmonChowdhury but this is flutter, any idea?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration follow this link to migrate to AndroidX

Comment: @AmonChowdhury i've tried it before but not fully successfully, face many errors. now i'm rethinking again to develop apps using flutter. I will return to Android Native...

Comment: There are many people reporting building problems after 1.20 update. There is no easy way to check which packages have been broken. The problem is not flutter, but the package ecosystem. Check the smaller packages, usually mantained by a single person or a small team. The bigger packages usually are uptaded frequently.

Comment: @racr0x is this the root cause of problem ? see https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/17305

Comment: We can't know for sure. Probably there will be a solution soon.

Comment: @racr0x however, i see a strange in fluter. in my `pubspec.yaml` i declare/use old 3rd plugin version number but why i got update of their new update. this is not the first time.

Comment: Probably beacause you are using ^. Look: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages

Answer (score 0):

Could you try updating your firebase packages dependencies?

Comment: the latest version of each, firebase_messaging, firebase_auth etc. you can run `pub upgrade` to display the outdated packages

Answer (score 0):

Flutter app crashes at startup are mainly caused by the any Package dependency issue

causing error can be debug via following command inside project folder into terminal

```
adb logcat
```

in your case `08-17 11:18:42.282 12595 12600 I zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB 08-17 11:18:42.283 12595 12595 I CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful 08-17 11:18:42.285 12595 12595 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM`

it seems crashlytics error

check if you have applied required dependency in android/app/build.gradle
as shown in picture

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

[image]

`adb logcat` can provide the detail for exact error causing issue

Answer (score 0):

project build.gradle

Whether androidx.core version is specified

Similar to the following

```
rootProject.allprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core') {
                details.useVersion "1.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If so, delete it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with codemagic this week, but when I built locally and pushed to Google Play Console/App Store Connect the app runs successfully. Maybe an issue coming from codemagic?